# Splitting multi-tier data into 5 folds using python

Tags: python, csv, split, cross-validation

I am completely stuck as to where to start with this. I am trying to do a 5-fold cross validation on my dataset but first need to get the data into 5 folds.

Problem 1: The data needs to be split by recording (file name) so that all recordings from the same individual are in the same fold and do not split between test and training dataset.

Problem 2: I need to split the data into 80% training and 20% test according to filename (i.e. recording)

Problem 3: The training and test data needs to be split across 5 folds (again by filename)

So I need to generate a 10 CSV files which list the features in the [current dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdMof.png), a test and training CSV, 1 for each fold.

I am trying to code this in python and would really appreciate any tips and advice. Thanks, let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: What are your labels? What do you want to predict? Genus? Species? If you give me more information I might be able to give you some advice.

Comment: so i am trying to classify bats using a random forest classifier, to species using their calls, so i need the recordings in 5 folds to compare with each other. what do you mean by labels?

Comment: Do you only have one .csv file? Are you able to share this file by providing a link? Or is this data private? The first thing you want to do is to get familiar with pandas which allows you to read your .csv file easily. There are plenty of tutorials out there that explain how to do that. Please ask further questions when you got stuck but try to do it on your own as far as you can.

Comment: it is a single CSV file, unfortunately I cannot share it, but it is a very big version of the image I posted. Thanks for the tip about pandas, I will take a look at that and see how far I get,